# Edit Item Using Vuex and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong when trying to edit an item. I've managed to make it work using firebase within component state but I cannot get it to work using vuex.

**Firebase Flow:**

[image]

**Error when trying to edit:**

[image]

Here's my code. I'm commented out the code that works in my `editItem` method and included my mutated function from my store which doesn't work.

**Store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import database from './firebase'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    items: []
  },

  mutations: {
    RENDER_ITEMS(state) {
      database.ref('items').on('value', snapshot => {
        state.items = snapshot.val()
      })
    },

    ADD_ITEM(state, payload) {
      state.items = payload
      database.ref('items').push(payload)
    },

    REMOVE_ITEM(index) {
      database.ref(`items/${index}`).remove()
    },

    EDIT_ITEM(state, index, payload) {
      database.ref(`items/${index}`).set(payload)
    }
  },

  // actions: {

  // }
})
```

**Main.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" v-model="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="age" v-model="age">
    <input type="text" placeholder="status" v-model="status">
    <input type="submit" @click="addItem" />
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        {{ item.name }}
        {{ item.age }}
        {{ item.status }}
        <button @click="removeItem(index)">Remove</button>
        <button @click="editItem(index, item)">Edit</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'
import database from '../firebase' // TEST REASONS
import uuid from 'uuid'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',

  created() {
    this.RENDER_ITEMS(this.items)
  },

  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
      age: '',
      status: '',
      id: uuid(),
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'items'
    ])
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([
      'RENDER_ITEMS',
      'ADD_ITEM',
      'REMOVE_ITEM',
      'EDIT_ITEM'
    ]),

    addItem() {
      const item = {
        name: this.name,
        age: this.age,
        status: this.status,
        id: this.id
      }

      this.ADD_ITEM(item)

      this.name = ''
      this.age = ''
      this.status = ''
    },

    removeItem(index) {          
      this.REMOVE_ITEM(index)
    },

    editItem(index, item) {
      const payload = {
        name: item.name,
        age: item.age,
        status: item.status
      }

      this.EDIT_ITEM(index, payload) // THIS DOESN'T
      // database.ref(`items/${index}`).set(payload) THIS WORKS //
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the `payload` parameter, being the 3rd, is `undefined`, because...

The function signature of [Mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) is always in the form of `(state, payload)`, that means the data must come in `Object` form, like this:

```
this.EDIT_ITEM({
    key: index,
    value: payload
})
```

Then on your function declaration:

```
EDIT_ITEM(state, payload) {
    database.ref(`items/${payload.key}`).set(payload.value)
}
```

I changed the payload variable names just to make the distinction clear, hope it doesn't adds to the confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that you could've done this but now I know. :)